# redirecting to error page on failed send password notification

Tags: laravel

[image]

use AuthenticableTrait, Notifiable, CanResetPassword, HasRoles, TwoFactorAuthentication,SendsPasswordResetEmails;

```
protected $fillable = ['auth_method', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password', 'contact_number_country_code', 'contact_number', 'is_admin', 'is_sso_auth', 'status', 'last_login', 'require_mfa'];
protected $appends = ['full_name', 'avatar'];

public function sendPasswordResetNotification($token)
{
    // try {
        $this->notify(new AdminResetPasswordNotification($token));
    // }
    // catch(\Exception $e){

    //     return view('admin');
    // }
}

public function verifyUser()
{
    return $this->hasOne(VerifyUser::class, 'user_id');
}
```

Comment: What is the point of the question?

Comment: if the admin has wrong smtp configuration users wont be able to receive forget password email, that functions notifies the user  after email validation but as admin has given wrong credentials i want to redirect them with error request message. I am kind of starting so!

Comment: public function sendPasswordResetNotification($token)
    {
        try {
             $this->notify(new AdminResetPasswordNotification($token));
        }
        catch(\Exception $e){
            return redirect()->back()->with('msg', 'Error');
        }
            

    }